# How to unit test methods that use System.Web.Security.Membership inside?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I want to test a method to check that it saves a transaction correctly.  Inside it calls Membership.GetUser() to verify the user which causes the test to fail each time. Is there any way to mock this so that Membership.GetUser() always returns a valid name?

I'm using Moq, C# and ASP.Net 4.5 MVC

Answer (score 5):

In short, you can't. That's why every call to such a "service" should be hidden behind an abstraction.

You can see a sample of that in default MVC template.

Comment: Can you elaborate? The template uses WebSecurity.Login(). What's a good way to abstract that so that the unit tests don't actually hit the database?

Comment: Found this that looks promising: http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/unit-testing-the-mvc4-account-controller. Is that the kind of abstraction you are talking about?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, like Serg said, you can mock this by providing an interface for the real service to implement. This interface would have the public methods you are calling, such as:

```
public interface IMyServiceInterface
{
    IMembershipUser GetUser();
    // other methods you want to use...
}
```

In your unit tests, you would say:

```
var mockService = new Mock<IServiceInterface>();
mockService.Setup(mock => mock.GetUser()).
    Returns(new MembershipUserImplementation("MyTestUser", otherCtorParams));
```

In my example I would create a wrapper for MembershipUser as well as it seems like it also needs to be behind an abstraction.

Comment: Which mocking framework are you using in the example?

Comment: I use [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/). It's simple and does everything I need it to do.